# Pass Array Elements To Heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

I'm trying to pass an array elements to heredoc, the goal is to produce a file, for example:

```
declare -a box=("element1" "element2" "element3")

cat > test.txt <<-EOF
some text, insert first element
some text, insert second element
some text, insert third element
EOF
```

Is this possible?, How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can

```
cat > test.txt <<-EOF
some text, ${box[0]}
some text, ${box[1]}
some text, ${box[2]}
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

You can nest a loop with `$(..)`:

```
declare -a box=("element1" "element2" "element3")

cat > test.txt <<-EOF
Greetings,

Here are the elements you wanted:
$(
    for s in "${box[@]}"
    do
      echo "some text, $s"
    done
 )

Happy New Year from $USER
EOF
```

When executed, this produces a `test.txt` containing:

```
Greetings,

Here are the elements you wanted:
some text, element1
some text, element2
some text, element3

Happy New Year from myusername
```

Comment: Thank you, What does $(..) do?

Comment: It's called command substitution. It runs the command inside the `$(..)`, captures its stdout, and substitutes that in. For example: `echo "The time is now $(date)"` will run `date`, capture `Thu Jan  3 14:06:27 PST 2019`, and insert that into the string

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to explain this, thank you.

Comment: Is it posibble to build a heredoc dynamically inside a loop using a string element inside an array?

Comment: A heredoc is meant as a template where you can insert the result of variables and commands. If you don't really have a template and want build everything dynamically, don't use a here doc. Just write a function that outputs anything you want in any order, and redirect the function to your file

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to follow your advice.